# Accessing Oracle 10g (and higher) from .Net 2.0?

Tags: oracle, .net-2.0, oracle10g

I have yet to find a good comparison of technologies for accessing Oracle from .Net applications...

Are there significant differences between Microsoft's **System.Data.OracleClient** provider and Oracle's **Oracle.DataAccess.Client**? My current company is using both because they couldn't figure out how to return a cursor from an oracle function using System.Data.OracleClient. (I fixed that for them, so that is not a factor) For dynamic sql queries, they prefer to use System.Data.OracleClient as they feel that Oracle.DataAccess.Client is "picky" and causes other problems in general.

**Edit: Deprecation of the System.Data.OracleClient types is not a concern**

Other than Deprecation of System.Data.OracleClient, are there significant reasons to lean one way or the other for new development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a [comparison grid](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-154765.html) between Oracle ODP.net and Microsoft Oracle Client help?